# unnamed namespace results in value being improper

Tags: c++

I am on windows 7 machine with visual studio 2015 community edition .

Consider the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

namespace 
{
    int y=4;
    int x=6;
}
int u = ::y;
int y = ::y; 
int x = 567;



int main()
{
    cout << u << "\n";
    cout << ::x << "\n";
    //cout << y << "\n";
    cout<< ::y << "\n";
    int y2;

    cin >> y2;
    return 0;
}
```

The result of the program is :

4
567
0

If we see u and x are right but y is wrong . why ?

Answer (score 3):

```
int y = ::y
```

Here the second `y` is the same as the first - the variable is initialized with its own value. Since it's a global variable, its own value is zero.

Once a declaration introduces a name `y` into the global namespace, there's no syntax to access `y` from the unnamed namespace. A variable declaration is visitble from its own initializer.

Comment: But the u is properly referencing properly to 4 . Shouldn't  compiler either complain or give right value  4.

Comment: At the point where `u` is declared, only the declaration of `y` from unnamed namespace is visible, so that's the one being used.